# Equivlent to SUM(CASE WHEN...) in WHERE

Tags: postgresql

POSTGRES 9.4: I need to put an "if" function on WHERE but the only way I know is to SUM a CASE WHEN function. Since you can't use aggregate functions on WHERE, it doesn't work. Does anyone know a way to do so? (The query below has been edited due to the answers given me, but still is taking forever to execute. Can anyone help me?)

My query:

```
SELECT companies.id
  , avg(char_length(field_answers.comment))
  , count(distinct(field_answers.id))
  , count(distinct(surveys.id))


FROM contracts
JOIN companies on contracts.company_id = companies.id
JOIN surveys on companies.id = surveys.company_id
JOIN fields on surveys.id = fields.owner_id
JOIN field_answers on fields.id = field_answers.field_id
JOIN participants on surveys.id = participants.survey_id

WHERE fields.owner_type = 'Survey'
AND surveys.stage in ('finished', 'closed', 'active')

GROUP BY companies.id

HAVING sum(case when participants.finished = 'true' then 1 else 0 end) > 0.9 * count(participants.id)
```

Comment: You want `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`?

Comment: Or, if HAVING wouldn't work for some reason (depending on your requirements) you can nest the query and in the outter query you apply the filter?

Comment: You forgot basic information to make the question clear: what is the query supposed to do? Show the full `FROM` clause and your version of Postgres.

Comment: Your greatly modified question is now about query performance. For that, please include `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output.

Comment: Ok, I am new to this site. I noticed I got one negative grade. Should I delete this question and do another since it now changed?

Comment: Please do not completely change your question after you have received and answer. If you want to ask something different, ask a new question (and please read: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions before doing that)

Answer (score 0):

You use windows functions for processing like this.

You forgot to tell us what the grouping for the `sum` and `count` is, but let's assume that you want to aggregate by the attribute `team`.

Then you'd do it somewhat like this:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM (SELECT id,
             name,
             sum(finished::integer) OVER (PARTITION BY team) finished_per_team,
             count(1) OVER (PARTITION BY team) team_size
      FROM participants
     ) part_with_stats
WHERE finished_per_team > 0.9 * team_size;
```

Comment: The thing is that I do not want finished per team on the SELECT, but if it is the best solution I am open to do so. The thing is that the query is taking a long time to execute due to the table participants being really big, and I am affraid that putting more things on SELECT will make the query take longer to execute. :/

Comment: The answer was based on a quite different question, so it doesn't fit any more. It seems like you changed your question completely and it is now a question about performance.